# jquery get target value for href

Tags: jquery

Using jquery how do I find out the target value of a href link.  e.g. if my link was

```
<a href="someurl.com" id="the_link" target="_blank">link</a>
```

the target would be _blank

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#the_link').attr('target');
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/fG6hg/).

Answer (score 5):

I'll be different and teach you part-vanilla js by acting directly on the elements properties:

```
$('#the_link')[0].target;
```

---

If you're using **jQuery >=1.6** you should be using `.prop` than `.attr` really

```
$('#the_link').prop('target');
```

- [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr/6057122#6057122)

Comment: `$('#the_link')` is defintely not vanilla JavaScript.  You want `document.getElementById('the_link').target`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
alert($('#the_link').attr('target'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
$('#the_link').attr('target');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').attr('target')
```

Should do it

([jQuery .attr Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/))

Comment: This will collect all `'a'` elements. Better select by ID

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is correct for the specific case shown in the OP's example, in a real-world scenario, it's entirely possible that a link's effective target won't be defined as an attribute of its anchor element.

For example, consider this basic HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <base target="_blank">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="someurl.com" id="the_link">link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Due to the `<base target="_blank">` element in the `<head>`, the link's target is `_blank`, but this:

```
$('#the_link').attr('target');
```

will return `undefined` because the link has no `target` attribute.

A more effective approach might be something like:

```
function getTarget($link) {
  var linkTarget = $link.attr('target'),
      baseTarget = $('base').attr('target');
  if (typeof linkTarget !== 'undefined') {
    return linkTarget;
  } else if (typeof baseTarget !== 'undefined') {
    return baseTarget;
  }
}       

console.log(getTarget($('#the_link'));
```

That will return the link's target if defined, otherwise the base target if defined, otherwise `undefined`.